What's the importance of the Approximation Theorem - Artin-Whaples Approximation Theorem


The above pictures present the statement of the approximation theorem by Artin-Whaples and its corollary in their paper. I do understand that the theorem implies that we can use one element to approximate distinct points with respect to inequivalent valuations at any given accuracy.
I believe this statement is very strong and useful, but I can't see how. I have a feeling that this may be related to certain local-global phenomena.
Maybe the following paper is related.
Mantova, Vincenzo; Zannier, Umberto, Artin-Whaples approximations of bounded degree in algebraic varieties.
